# How to i get this filling patern?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, pattern

How do we get this 3d efect on the rectangle uzing tikz? [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Maybe the following has some starting points: https://www.google.com/search?q=barchart:tex.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj68siJrqneAhULzaQKHVTKDs8QsAR6BAgGEAE

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Here I focus on the question how to get the plastic rectangles. The method I am using has the drawback that one needs to use a separate `\addplot` for each bar. This is because I am using `path picture`s, and for some reason there a single path picture for the whole plot, not for each bar. One can certainly simplify things by, say, drawing the bars in a loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{plastic bar/.style={preaction={
path picture={
\fill[blue!40] 
 ([xshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south west)  
 rectangle
 ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north east);
\fill[blue!80] 
 ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north east)
 -- (path picture bounding box.north east) --
 (path picture bounding box.south east) --  
 ([xshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.south east);  
\fill[blue!20] 
 ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north east)
 -- (path picture bounding box.north east) --
 (path picture bounding box.north west) --  
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north west);  
\fill[blue!60] 
 ([xshift=3pt,yshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.north west) --
 (path picture bounding box.south west) --  
 ([xshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.south west);  
}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,bar width=9,xmin=10,xmax=65,ymax=110,ymin=-5,bar shift=-10,
axis lines=middle,yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%$}]
\addplot[draw=none,plastic bar]  coordinates {(35,10)};
\addplot[draw=none,plastic bar]  coordinates {(45,30)};
\addplot[draw=none,plastic bar]  coordinates {(55,80)};
\addplot[draw=none,plastic bar]  coordinates {(65,100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i was loonking for a package, or s simple command... but one solution is better that no solution...
Thank you.

Comment: @PauloCorreia If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) by clicking on the arrows next to the score. If any of the answers solve your problem then mark the best solution as an [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) by clicking on the checkmark ✓.